# IPv6 connectivity test in C++

Tags: c++, testing, ipv6, connectivity

Is there any C++ function to test whether the computer on which my program is running supports IPv6 connectivity?

I need to know something like result of this page http://test-ipv6.com/, but in C++.

*EDIT:* I was trying to use `getifaddrs()`. But return value can be `AF_INET6 found`, because I really have IPv6 address set, but IPv6 connectivity does not work (probably because ISP). So is there some way how to check if IPv6 connectivity works indeed?

Comment: If your standard C library has the `<netinet/in6.h>` header, your implementation supports IPv6.

Comment: Can you try to make an TCP-over-IPv6 connection to port 80 (the web server) at test-ipv6.com and see if the connection attempt succeeds?  If it does, IPv6 must be set up; if not, something isn't working.

Comment: The configuration of the local computer doesn't give you any guarantees that you actually have working end-to-end IPv6 connectivity. The point of test-ipv6.com is that it actually tests resolving DNS records and downloading sample files over IPv6. That goes way beyond the scope of "testing whether the computer supports IPv6 in C++".

Comment: Your network interface may support IPv6, but if that IPv6 extends beyond your modem/router is a whole different story. You cannot verify that by looking into the computer settings, they won't give you any useful information. Unfortunately you will have to rely on external sources to tell if you are connecting to them via IPv6 or not most of the time, unless you have an interface connecting directly to the Internet, not via router.

Answer (score 2):

All modern operating systems support IPv6, so you don't have to worry about whether the protocol is available. (If it isn't, your program won't compile anyway.)

But the only way to determine if the computer actually has working IPv6 connectivity is to attempt an IPv6 connection.

This is actually [what Microsoft does with their network status indicator in Windows](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee126135(v=ws.10).aspx). They attempt to load a [URL from an IPv6-only web server](http://ipv6.msftncsi.com/ncsi.txt) and a [URL from an IPv4-only web server](http://www.msftncsi.com/ncsi.txt). If both of these fail, you get the yellow triangle with exclamation point over the network icon in the system tray.

Since I needed a similar functionality, but I also needed the actual IPv6 addresses, [I created my own public service](http://myip.addr.space/help) which includes this functionality (and several other things). So I have an [IPv6-only URL](http://ipv6.myip.addr.space/ip) which returns the public IPv6 address, and an [IPv4-only URL](http://ipv4.myip.addr.space/ip) which returns the public IPv4 address.

Because one of the URLs is *only* accessible via IPv6, and the other is *only* accessible via IPv4, you can independently verify connectivity for each protocol.

Either way, if your attempt to fetch the URL fails, you can examine the returned error to determine what the problem might be.