# How to test from userspace if the kernel supports IPv6?

Tags: c, linux, sockets, tcp, userspace

I am seeking for a simple way to test if the kernel supports IPv6 on Linux in C/C++.
Is it enough to check if the socket() call fails and that errno is set to EINVAL ?

Comment: This is C++, but relevant: http://stackoverflow.com/q/13441324/656243

Answer (score 3):

Indeed, read [ipv6(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/ipv6.7.html): the call to [socket(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/socket.7.html)-s routines, notably [socket(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/socket.2.html) and others, e.g. [bind(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/bind.2.html) etc..., could fail (and you should *always* handle such failures anyway).

You could also use [proc(5)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/proc.5.html) e.g. read `/proc/net/if_inet6` or `/proc/net/sockstat6`  (I believe it won't exist if `ipv6` is unsupported).

Comment: Check for `/proc/net/if_inet6` instead.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it's safe to use [socket(7)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/socket.7.html), e.g.

```
#include <errno.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int is_ipv6_enabled(void) {
  int ret = 0;

#ifdef AF_INET6
  int fd = socket(AF_INET6, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
  if (fd == -1) {
    ret = errno != EAFNOSUPPORT;
  } else {
    ret = 1;
    close(fd);
  }
#endif /* AF_INET6 */

  return ret;
}
```