# Python Paramiko and IPV6 SSH

Tags: python, ssh, paramiko

I have to write a script that executes some commands on a remote machine using SSH. I had used paramiko for this and everything worked as long as I used IPv4 addressing. I had to switch IPv6 addressing and I can't seem to get Paramiko client to connect.

```
import paramiko
s = paramiko.SSHClient()
ip6_addr = 'fe80::1112:bcde:789a:1234'
s.connect (ip6_addr, username='foo', password='bar')
```

Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/paramiko/client.py", line 290, in connect
    sock.connect(addr)
  File "<string>", line 1, in connect
socket.error: [Errno 22] Invalid argument
```

Is there an example on how to specify the ip6 address to paramiko?

Answer (score 5):

You have to specify the interface name as well.

```
ip6_addr = 'fe80::1112:bcde:789a:1234%<interface>'
```

Following example is valid IPv6:

```
ip6_addr = 'fe80::1112:bcde:789a:1234%eth0'
```

Answer (score 0):

On my Python2.7.9 (which is also not the latest) and paramiko-1.15.2, I have no Problems.

Have you tried upgrading paramiko?

```
pip install --upgrade paramiko
```

EDIT:
Another idea, maybe your kernel does not support ipv6.
[How to test from userspace if the kernel supports IPv6?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28097823/how-to-test-from-userspace-if-the-kernel-supports-ipv6)