# ParallelSSHClient() with IPv6

Tags: python, ssh, parallel-ssh

What's the correct way to specify IPv6 addresses to ParallelSSHClient?

Not much is said here:
https://parallel-ssh.readthedocs.io/en/latest/quickstart.html
I've tried like [xxxx:xxxx:xxxx:xxxx:xxxx:xxxx:xxxx:xxxx] and also without the square brackets and I always get this:

```
output = client.run_command(ssh_cmd)

Could not resolve host '[xxxx:xxxx:xxxx:xxxx:xxxx:xxxx:xxxx:xxxx]' - retry 1/3
```

Comment: Looks like it doesn't understand IPv6 addresses. Can you use hostnames instead?

Comment: I also tried defining host names in C:\Windows\system32\drivers\etc\hosts and I can ssh from the terminal with those names, but not from parallel-ssh. To answer the obvious question, yes, I have restarted the PC already :)

Comment: I think it uses Paramiko, so https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31956313/python-paramiko-and-ipv6-ssh may be helpful.